# gulp-order : not Ordering properly

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat

Gulp newbie here, I downloaded [gulp-order](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-order) for ordering js files when concating ***.js**
because some of my javascript files require **jquery** to load first.

Below are my gulpfile.js that have order,concat,rename & uglify.

```
var date = new Date();
var uniq = date.getTime();

gulp.task('admin-scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(['assets/admin/js/*.js','!assets/admin/js/respond.min.js','!assets/admin/js/html5shiv.js'])
        .pipe(order([
            "assets/admin/js/jquery.min.js",
            'assets/admin/js/*.js'
        ]))
        .pipe(concat(uniq+'admin.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets/admin/js/'))
        .pipe(rename(uniq+'admin.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets/admin/js/'));
});
```

But seems the ordering is not working.

the ordering is base on alphabet **a.js > z.js** instead of **jquery.min.js > a.js > z.js**

is there anything I'd code wrongly on the gulpfile.js?

Comment: gulp-order is working exactly as expected.. it order files by their name and does not consider their position in the input source.. it does not have any way of exclude file from ordering or keep these files at top kind of functionality...

Comment: to inject jquery etc... you should use gulp-wiredep... and just order files that you develop... wiredep will order files based on dependency graph

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem my gulp-order not ordering properly / not working is because I'd put wrong path, the path should be relative to the **js** folder:

correct order : **jquery.min.js**

incorrect order : **assets/admin/js/jquery.min.js**

```
var date = new Date();
var uniq = date.getTime();

gulp.task('admin-scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(['assets/admin/js/*.js','!assets/admin/js/respond.min.js','!assets/admin/js/html5shiv.js'])
        .pipe(order([
            "jquery.min.js",
            '*.js'
        ]))
        .pipe(concat(uniq+'admin.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets/admin/js/'))
        .pipe(rename(uniq+'admin.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets/admin/js/'));
});
```

Answer (score 12):

adding [base](https://github.com/sirlantis/gulp-order#base) option fixed it for me:

```
.pipe(order([
      'public/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js',
      'public/js/bootstrap.min.js'
    ], { base: './' }))
```

Comment: Working well, with {base} all works fine and with proper order. Thanks!

Comment: For me, I had to do { base: '../' } - I am not 100% sure why, I only have theories.

Comment: `'./'` is for current directory. `'../'` goes up one directory.