# Gulp-terser not minfying in order

Tags: javascript, gulp, terser

I'm using gulp-terser to minify js files.  I have a jquery file and a custom js file.  When I try to run the task, the custom js code is at the beginning of the jquery file.  I've tried using gulp-order with it, but still no luck.
Here's the code i'm using:

```
gulp.task('build-js', function () {
    return gulp.src(["src/js/jquery.min.js","src/js/zinv.js"])
        .pipe(concat('inv.min.js'))
        .pipe(terser())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));
});
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: you want the jquery file at the beginning when you run the task ?

Comment: correct, inv.min.js needs jquery, so need jquery first.

Comment: i've also tried this, with no luck:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370600/gulp-order-not-ordering-properly

Comment: Did you try `return gulp.src(["src/js/zinv.js","src/js/jquery.min.js"])` ? Because I think the first src is the last in the order :)

Comment: yes, i tried that, unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Can you share you run command in the end ?

Comment: Do you want absolutly use terser ?

Comment: > cmd.exe /c gulp -b "C:\Users\repos\NodejsConsoleApp1" --color --gulpfile "C:\Users\repos\NodejsConsoleApp1\Gulpfile.js" build-js

Comment: using terser because my boss wants to and we were getting errors trying uglify and minify

Comment: Try to write `.pipe(terser())` before `.pipe(concat('inv.min.js'))`

Comment: I wrote an answer, try it and tell me what is going on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to switch the position of `.pipe(terser())` and `.pipe(concat('inv.min.js'))` and call the `require()`.

Try this :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var terser = require('gulp-terser');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src(["src/js/jquery.min.js","src/js/zinv.js"])
        .pipe(terser())
        .pipe(concat('inv.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('js'));
```

And then on your terminal, navigate to the directory where your gulpfile.js is saved and type `gulp` or `gulp js`

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work by moving tersor up a step:

```
gulp.task('build-js', function () {
    return gulp.src(["src/js/jquery.min.js","src/js/zinv.js"])
        .pipe(terser())
        .pipe(concat('inv.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));
})
```